# Graph api url to add members into azure active directory security group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need a Graph api url that can be used in postman to add member into existing azure active directory security group

Comment: Hello, this question is very vague. Here is the API documentation to add members to a security group. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph api url that can add member into existing azure active directory security group is

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 30

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}
```

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more details.

To call graph api, you need to get an access token first. Here are two ways to get the access token.

**1.Client Credentials Flow**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/21/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-client-credentials/

**2.Authorization Code Flow**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/23/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-authorization-code-flow/

**Note:** Client Credentials Flow needs **Application permission**, Authorization Code Flow needs **Delegated permission**.

[image]

**Update:**
This api also works for security group. I have added a user to the security group successfully.

[image]

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id} this url is used to add members into only into  Office 365 groups.which is mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Comment: @sqldeveloper No, this also works for security group. I have tested for you.

Comment: {"status":"Error","remarks":"{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "77ed163d-f41d-4ec1-bc22-f6a2k92d9fu1",
      "date": "2019-09-16T09:21:59"
    }
  }
}"}

Comment: I am getting error can you please specify the permissions required to add user to group

Comment: @sqldeveloper If you use client credencials flow, it should be `Group.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All`(Application permission). If you use Authorization Code Flow, it should be `Group.ReadWrite.All`(Delegated permission).

Comment: getting same issue even after giving required permission

Comment: @sqldeveloper Which flow did you use? Please add a screenshot about your api permission in azure portal. I guess you haven't grant admin consent.

Comment: @Tonu Ju      https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUCaPGtM2P4/XYCZdItGruI/AAAAAAAAA2s/FJfBJyK5ObIQsEJ65o8-CgKMvcvjtqQGQCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2019-09-17.png                                                        I am using Authorization Code Flow ,above screenshot shows the permissions given

Comment: @sqldeveloper The permissions are ok, can I have your request url? And you can decode the accesstoken to chech the permissions. https://jwt.io/

Comment: @sqldeveloper It also seems fine. Can you create a new security group and try again?