# Could not complete OAuth 2.0 Login

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

Hi I have created application in azure AD. I am trying to get token from Postman.
I am getting below error. Could not complete OAuth 2.0 Login. 
Below is my request.

[image]

My auth url is

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

In the above url, In place of organizations do i need to put my company name? Also do i need to add resource to the url? Can someone help me to try to find out error? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above url, In place of organizations do i need to put my
>   company name?

It depends on your requirements, if you just want your tenant(company) user to login(Single tenant), use tenant name/id here, if you want both your tenant and other tenants to login, you can use common/organizations here(Multitenant).

> Also do i need to add resource to the url?

No, you need a scope value instead of resource. This is what you want the user to consent to.

> Could not complete OAuth 2.0 Login in postman

1.Register an application in Azure portal

[image]

2.The parameters in postman.

**Auth URL:** 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

**Access Token URL:** `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

[image]

I am using Authorization Code flow to get the access token, you can also use Client Credentials flow. Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57916175/10504999).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For authorisation flow no need to set implicit grant flow true in manifest right? Also from where I can get client secrete?

Comment: I have gone through your blog. I will try with authorisation code flow. If I want implicit grant flow then how can I do? Is there any article related to it? Also which is good one to go authorisation code flow or implicit flow?

Comment: @Niranjan Click your application->Certificaste&secrets->New client secret, then you can get one secret.

Comment: @Niranjan Implicit grant flow allows an application to request a token directly from the authorization endpoint. Recommended only if the application has a single page architecture (SPA), has no backend components, or invokes a Web API via JavaScript. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow for more details.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. Also after some reading I came to know we need to add scope rather than resource as you said. So scope I should add in scope field or I should append it to auth url? Also scope is just a string or do we need to configure scope in azure portal?

Comment: @Niranjan Just add the value in scope field.

Comment: Also in your blog you have mentioned auth url should be https://login.microsoftonline.com/8839a17c-5ebf-496f-858e-0bd6c3038589/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com. But now for my knowledge we should not send resource in auth url. Just confused in this step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199394/discussion-between-tony-ju-and-niranjan).